# Problema con gradle en android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

actualicé android studio y tuve que actualizar gradle y demás el tema es que éste no me sincroniza, alguien me puede ayudar a configurar gradle? Gracias desde ya.

module: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.damian.xxx.miapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 21
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

module: project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    //mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
```

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Damián pon el texto completo del `gradle`, lo puedes hacer [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/212557/edit). Aquí una imagen sirve de muy poco. Gracias.

Comment: ok, gracias por la sugerencia. Ya modifiqué la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Ese es el gradle del módulo `app` o del proyecto. El error menciona dependencias que no aparecen en el archivo que has compartido. ¿Dónde agregas esas dependencias? Debes ponerlas todas en la misma versión, que es la `28`. Es lo que dice el mensaje de error, usas dependencias por ejemplo de la versión `27`.

Comment: Ahí especifiqué el código de los 2 archivos. Pero me diste una pista de lo que debe ser, las dependencias probablemente.

Comment: Habla de dependencias como `animated-vector...` o  `custom-tabs...` que no veo por ningún lado, no sé donde estás agregando esas dependencias. El mensaje de error imagino que te indicará dónde se encuentran para poder ponerlas todas en su  versión `28.0.0` Me extraña que no estén en el `gradle`